# CLPFD ins operator yields not sufficiently instantiated error

Tags: prolog, clpfd

So, my goal is to make a map colourer in Prolog. Here's the map I'm using:

[image]

And this are my colouring constraints:

```
colouring([A,B,C,D,E,F]) :- 
    maplist( #\=(A), [B,C,D,E] ),
    maplist( #\=(B), [C,D,F]),
    C #\= D,
    maplist( #\=(D), [E,F]),
    E #\= F.
```

Where [A,B,C,D,E,F] is a list of numbers(colors) from 1 to n.

So I want my solver to, given a List of 6 colors and a natural number N, determine the colors and N constraints both ways, in a way that even the most general query could yield results:

```
regions_ncolors(L,N) :- colouring(L), L ins 1..N, label(L).
```

Where the most general query is `regions_ncolors(L,N).`

However, the operator `ins` doesn't seem to accept a variable N, it instead yields an argument not sufficiently instantiated error. I've tried using this solution instead:

```
int_cset_(N,Acc,Acc) :- N #= 0.
int_cset_(N,Acc,Cs) :- N_1 #= N-1, int_cset_(N_1,[N|Acc],Cs).
int_cset(N,Cs) :- int_cset_(N,[],Cs).

% most general solver
regions_ncolors(L,N) :- colouring(L), int_cset(N,Cs), subset(L,Cs), label(L).
```

Where the arguments in `int_cset(N,Cs)` is a natural number(N) and the counting set Sn = {1,2,...,N}

But this solution is buggy as `regions_ncolors(L,N).` only returns the same(one) solution for all N, and when I try to add a constraint to N, it goes in an infinite loop.

So what can I do to make the most general query work both ways(for not-instantiated variables)?

Thanks in advance!

Btw, I added a `swi-prolog` tag in my last post although it was removed by moderation. I don't know if this question is specific to `swi-prolog` which is why I'm keeping the tag, just in case :)

Comment: There are moderators who really hate it when you tag supposedly general questions with a specific Prolog implementation. Since they are **moderate**ing they do sometimes go to extremes with it.

Comment: @TA_intern The OP used the word moderator and then you used the word moderator in your comment. Who are you both talking about? The staff moderators, the elected moderators? Did either of you check to see who made the change? Many who change tags are not moderators, I change tags and I am not a moderator. I personally like seeing swi-prolog used more as a tag so I am not deleting them. I do know who does it regularly but that is their privilege.

Comment: @GuyCoder Oh, I see, I didn't know that! Apparently it wasn't a mod that deleted the tag, just a seasoned stack overflow user.

Comment: @GuyCoder I am moderately confused by Stackoverflow and its hierarchy of power, so please forgive me. The bottom line is, the privilege has yet again been exercised and the tag has been removed.

Comment: Note that `int_cset(1, Cs)` does not terminate.

Comment: @false Oh I see. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @false But how come? I'm getting baffled by this, the same thing is happening on my binary tree code!

Comment: I answered your question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `colouring` is too specific, you  encode the topology of your map into it. Not a problem as is, but it defeats of the purpose of then having a "most general query" solution for just any list.

If you want to avoid the problem of having a free variable instead of a list, you could first instantiate the list with `length/2`. Compare:

```
?- L ins 1..3.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [16] throw(error(instantiation_error,_86828))
ERROR:   [10] clpfd:(_86858 ins 1..3) ...
```

Is that the same problem as you see?

If you first make a list and a corresponding set:

```
?- length(L, N), L ins 1..N.
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [1],
N = 1 ;
L = [_A, _B],
N = 2,
_A in 1..2,
_B in 1..2 ;
L = [_A, _B, _C],
N = 3,
_A in 1..3,
_B in 1..3,
_C in 1..3 .
```

If you use `length/2` like this you will enumerate the possible lists and integer sets completely outside of the CLP(FD) labeling. You can then add more constraints on the variables on the list and if necessary, use labeling.

Does that help you get any further with your problem? I am not sure how it helps for the colouring problem. You would need a different representation of the map topology so that you don't have to manually define it within a predicate like your `colouring/1` you have in your question.

Comment: Oh thanks for that, ```length(L,N)``` does work well for me! In particular, I'm using ```length([_|_],N)``` to generate all N from 1 to N and It's been working great. About the map constraints, yeah I know they need to be upgraded to be truly general, but I don't really want to make a super map colourer, for now I'm just learning how to use CLPFD first

Comment: Small typo: length/2, not lenght/2 in the next-to-last paragraph. I don't have the rights to just fix it.

Comment: @jnmonette thank you, I try to copy-paste any real code but this was just me typing too fast. Fixed :+1:

Comment: @Luiz: your mentioned goal `length([_|_],N)` will only terminate if `N` is known. But `length(L,N)` will also terminate if the length of `L` is known.

Comment: @ Oh I see! But, in this case I'm not using L for anything other than generating N. Here's my solver:
```regions_ncolors(L,N) :- length([_|_],N), colouring(L), L ins 1..N, label(L).```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your program.

#### subset/2 is impure

SWI's (by default) built-in predicate `subset/2` is not the pure relation you are hoping for.  Instead, it expects that both arguments are already sufficiently instantiated. And if not, it takes a guess and sticks to it:

```
?-            colouring(L), subset(L,[1,2,3,4,5]).
   L = [1,2,3,4,2,1].

?-            colouring(L), subset(L,[1,2,3,4,5]), L = [2|_].
   false.

?- L = [2|_], colouring(L), subset(L,[1,2,3,4,5]), L = [2|_].
   L = [2,1,3,4,1,2].
```

With a pure definition it is impossible that adding a further goal as `L = [2|_]` in the third query makes a failing query succeed.

In general it is a good idea to not interfere with `labeling/2` except for the order of variables and the options argument.  The internal implementation is often much faster than manual instantiations.

Also, your map is far too simple to expose `subset/2`s weakness.  Not sure what the minimal failing graph is, but here is one such example from

> R. Janczewski et al. The smallest hard-to-color graph for algorithm DSATUR, Discrete Mathematics 236 (2001) [p.164](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82314213.pdf#page=14).

```
colouring_m13([K1,K2,K3,K6,K5,K7,K4]):-
    maplist(#\=(K1), [K2,K3,K4,K7]),
    maplist(#\=(K2), [K3,K5,K6]),
    maplist(#\=(K3), [K4,K5]),
    maplist(#\=(K4), [K5,K7]),
    maplist(#\=(K5), [K6,K7]),
    maplist(#\=(K6), [K7]).

?-            colouring_m13(L), subset(L,[1,2,3,4]).
   false.                   % incomplete

?- L = [3|_], colouring_m13(L), subset(L,[1,2,3,4]).
   L = [3,1,2,2,3,1,4].
```

#### int_cset/2 never terminates

... (except for some error cases like `int_cset(non_integer, _).`).  As an example consider:

```
?- int_cset(1,Cs).
   Cs = [1]
;  loops.
```

And don't get fooled by the fact that an actual solution was found! It still does not terminate.

> @Luis: But how come? I'm getting baffled by this, the same thing is happening on ...

To see this, you need the notion of a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) which helps to identify the responsible part in your program. With some falsework consisting of goals **`false`** the responsible part is exposed.

All unnecessary parts have been removed by **`false`**. What remains has to be changed *somehow*.

```
int_cset_(N,Acc,Acc) :- false, N #= 0.
int_cset_(N,Acc,Cs) :- N1 #= N-1, int_cset_(N1,[N|Acc],Cs), false.

int_cset(N,Cs) :- int_cset_(N,[],Cs), false.

?- int_cset(1, Cs), false.
   loops.
```

Adding the redundant goal `N1 #> 0`
will avoid unnecessary non-termination.

This alone will not solve your problem since if `N` is not given, you will still encounter non-termination due to the following failure slice:

```
regions_ncolors(L,N) :-
   colouring(L),
   int_cset(N,Cs), false,
   subset(L,Cs),
   label(L).
```

In `int_cset(N,Cs)`, `Cs` occurs for the first time and thus cannot influence termination (there is another reason too, its definition would ignore it as well..) and therefore only `N` has a chance to induce termination.

The actual solution has been already suggested by @TA_intern using `length/2` which liberates one of such mode-infested chores.